# Enable user account in Active Directory from Perl

Tags: perl, ldap

How to enable user account in Active Directory from Perl if that account is disabled

I am using NET::LDAP . How its not working UserAccountControl Attribute

Comment: Are you referring to a particular CPAN module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Perl nor even `NET::LDAP`, but here's a link with the possible values for [*UserAccountControl* flags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144/en-us).

Hope this helps!